# пронумеровать выводимые строки

Tags: php, циклы

Есть вывод данных типа:

```
...
$query = "SELECT * FROM table";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  echo "<tr><td>", $row["a_id"], "</td><td>" ,$rowCity["a_name"], "</td></tr>";
...
```

из него получается несколько строк с html-ной табличке:

```
89    Вася
150   Петя
48    Маша
...
```

Подскажите, как мне добавить нумерацию, чтобы было так:

```
1   89    Вася
2   150   Петя
3   48    Маша
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$query  = "SELECT * FROM table";
$result = mysql_query($query);

$i = 1;    // индекс нужно поставить "1"
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr><td> " . $i++ . " - " . $row["a_id"] . "</td><td>" . $rowCity["a_name"] . "</td></tr>";
}
```

Удачного кодинга...